# android setOnItemLongClickListener conflict with textIsSelectable property set to true

Tags: android, conflict, behavior

hi all Android experts:

I have a listview item layout which uses a TextView, it is set to 
**android:textIsSelectable="true"**

In my activity I setup the list item long click on open the action menu:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            // Called when the user long-clicks on someView
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mActionMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }

                selectedLeaveId = position;

                // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
                mActionMode = MyActivity.this
                        .startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                view.setSelected(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

During runtime if I long click on the text of a list item, I get the action menu on top first. Then I long click on the text again I get the the text selection menu on top.

I am thinking of making set textisselectable to false, and add one more actual menu item to open the select text menu, however it sounds a wierd solution...

Is there a way to solve this conflict or this is actually a bad implementation that these 2 behaviors cannot co-exist?

thanks in advance